# How to POST data from python and GET it in NodeJS?

Tags: python, node.js, python-requests, node-request

I have a `NodeJS` `server` and I want to `GET` data that is coming from `python` with the `POST` method.

> pythonData.js

```
const router = require('express').Router()
    router.get("/data",(req,res)=>{
        console.log(res)
    })
    module.exports = router
```

> data.py

```
import requests
data = {"Car": "BMW","Testing":"API"}

request = requests.post("http://localhost:5000/python/data",data=data)
print(request.status_code)
print(request.text)
```

but when I run my `python` file I got an `error`

> 404
>
> Error
>
> ```
> Cannot POST
> /python/data
> ```

Also how do I `get` it in my `NodeJS`

Answer (score 1):

You have implemented a GET method in Node, but you are doing a POST from Python.

Try changing the `router.get` to `router.post` in your Express server.

Comment: I want to send data from my python script to nodejs server so that I can get it there in Nodejs

Answer (score 1):

You express router function is processing `GET` request.
Change this to process `POST` request.